# Change default size of JTree node icon for Windows L'n'F

Tags: java, swing, jtree, look-and-feel

When I change a default `JTree` node icon to an icon of a size 24x24 pixels via `UIManager` it is not rendered correctly to some reason. By this I mean the row size is somehow reduced and icon image is not visible in full size.

The same effect when I use the Custom `TreeRenderer`.

Problem occurs for Windows LaF. It is rendered correctly for Java native LaF.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `setRowHeight()` property, for [example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui).

*(answer taken from [trashgod's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17430896/change-default-size-of-jtree-node-icon-for-windows-lnf#comment25324143_17430896) - Jul 2 '13 at 19:23, as indicated by OP as the solution)*